# label.setText NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javafx, fxml, settext

Hi first time here but here goes:

I have a JavaFX application that changes the FXML UI labels dynamically and the data is pulled from a Player class.

The two classes in question are `Player.java` and `InterfaceHandler.java`.

The player class stores player details and I want to pass the details to the Interface class which sets the text on the labels.

As a test my FXML UI just has a button and two labels.

If it click the button it calls the `handleButton` method it sets `locationLabel` to "Town" fine.

However if I call the `locationLabel()` method in my Player class I get a NullPointerException when `nameLabel.setText(name)` is called. Through debugging I find that the name string in the Interface class is what it should be "Dan".

Can anyone help?

Main class:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public void start(final Stage mainStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        mainStage.setTitle("Main Screen");
        mainStage.setScene(scene);
        mainStage.show();    
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Player class:

```
public class Player{

InterfaceHandler ui = new InterfaceHandler();   

 public void setNameLabel() {

    String name = "Dan";
    ui.setName(name);
}
```

InterfaceHandler class:

```
    public class InterfaceHandler implements Initializable {

       public Label nameLabel;
       public Label locationLabel;    

public void handleButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {        

        locationLabel.setText("Town");
    }

public void setName(String name){       
        nameLabel.setText(name);
    }    
}
```

MainScreen.fxml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import java.net.*?>
    <?import java.util.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

    <AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="629.0" prefWidth="600.0" snapToPixel="true" style="-fx-background-color:  beige;" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="application.InterfaceHandler">
      <children>            
        <Button fx:id="button1" layoutX="512.0" layoutY="381.0" minWidth="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleButton" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="51.0" text="Town" visible="true" />        

        <Label fx:id="nameLabel" layoutX="57.0" layoutY="8.0" prefWidth="216.0" text="blank" />
        <Label fx:id="locationLabel" layoutX="68.0" layoutY="27.0" prefWidth="193.0" text="blank" />
      </children>
    </AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you didn't properly inject your `Labels` from FXML file.

Annotate your `Label` vars. with `FXML` annotation:

```
public class InterfaceHandler implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    public Label nameLabel;
    @FXML
    public Label locationLabel;    

    public void handleButton(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {        
        locationLabel.setText("Town");
    }

    public void setName(String name){       
        nameLabel.setText(name);
    }    
}
```

Also, InterfaceHandler is a controller which you reference with `fx:controller` in your FXML.  This instructs the FXMLLoader to create a new instance of the InterfaceHandler when the loader loads its FXML.  So don't create a new InterfaceHandler in your Player class, instead make InterfaceHandler a constructor parameter for Player and use loader.getController to get the InterfaceHandler controller instance out of the FXMLLoader.

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainScreen.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent)loader.load();
Player player = new Player(loader.getController());
Scene scene = new Scene(root);

. . .

public class Player {
  private InterfaceHandler ui;   

  public Player(InterfaceHandler ui) {
    this.ui = ui;
  }

  public void setNameLabel() {
    String name = "Dan";
    ui.setName(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! However I did have to add a cast to make it work: `Player player = new Player((InterfaceHandler) loader.getController());`

Comment: If you use NetBeans, use the make controller option to create the controller files from fxml. It will do the FXML injection for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but turns out that I had made the label as a static attribute and when I removed the static part it fixed the nullpointer exeption.